# read a file and assign key, values java

Tags: java, algorithm, greedy

so I'm trying to make a greedy/jewel heist algorithm in java. I saved the numbers and weights for the jewels to a .txt file. My program is correctly reading the .txt file and I've written a program that can successfully read them. these are the numbers from my .txt file

```
575 - bag limit
125 3000 (weight, value)
50 100
500 6000
25 30
```

The problem I'm running into is that I'm struggling to add weights and values to the program.  ideally the program would read the tuples and assign them keys and values. I tried to use a hashmap and a regular Map but they haven't been working. possibly because they're in the wrong place. I included both attempted maps and have them commented out like in my program. Would love some help on assigning these values so I can move on to the next step. thanks!!

```
    import java.io.BufferedReader;
    import java.io.File;
    import java.io.FileReader;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.nio.file.Files;
    import java.nio.file.Paths;
//    import java.util.HashMap;
//    import java.util.Map;
    public class readstringastext {

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            try {
                File file = new File("test.txt");
                FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(file);
                BufferedReader bufferedReader = new 
                BufferedReader(fileReader);
                StringBuffer stringBuffer = new StringBuffer();
                String line;
                String weightLimit = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get("test.txt")).get(0); 
                while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                    stringBuffer.append(line);
                    stringBuffer.append("\n");
                }
                fileReader.close();
    }       catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
    }
            HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
//
//          for (String string : pairs) {
//              String[] keyValue = string.split(" "); 
//              map.put(keyValue[0], keyValue[1]);
//              System.out.println(keyValue);
//      };
//final class MyEntry<K, V> implements Map.Entry<K, V> {
//  private final K key;
//  private V value;
//  
//  public MyEntry(K key, V value) {
//      this.key = key;
//      this.value = value;
//  }   
//  @Override 
//  public K getKey() {
//      return key;
//  }
//  
//  @Override 
//  public V getValue() {
//      return value;
//  }
//  
//  @Override
//  public V setValue(V value) {
//      V old = this.value;
//      this.value = value;
//      return old;
//  }
//  Map.Entry<String, Object> entry = new MyEntry <String, Object>(key, value);
//  System.out.println(entry.getKey());
//  System.out.println(entry.getValue());
}



    }
```

attempt 2

```
public class readstringastext {

    public static HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
    public static void weightLimit() {
        String weightLimit = "";
        System.out.println(weightLimit);
```

// this is to see if the weightLimit is there which it isnt'.
        }

public static void main(String[] args){

```
        try {
            File file = new File("test.txt");
            FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(file);
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(fileReader);
            String line;
            String weightLimit = "";
            boolean first = true;
            while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                if (first) {
                    weightLimit = line;
                    first = false;
                } else {
                    String[] values = line.split(" ");
                    map.put(values[0], values[1]);
                }
            }

            fileReader.close();
        }       catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see your code and and I see you read two times the file with `Files.readAllLines()` and `standard method`. So I suggest you this solution but you can use `Files.readAllLines()` too.

```
public class Main {

    public static HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
    private static String weightLimit = "";

    public static void main(String[] args){

        try {
            File file = new File("test.txt");
            FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(file);
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(fileReader);
            String line;
            boolean first = true;
            while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                if (first) {
                    weightLimit = line;
                    first = false;
                } else {
                    String[] values = line.split(" ");
                    map.put(values[0], values[1]);
                }

            }
            fileReader.close();
        }       catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        weightLimit();
    }

    public static void weightLimit() {
        System.out.println(weightLimit);
    }
}
```

Comment: This works! I've successfully printed the values[0] and values[1] but I can't print the String weightLimit and I'm not seeing where it is set to 575. I tried setting the weightLimit myself with my original String weightLimit = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get("test.txt")).get(0);      and then when I printed that it output 575 four times.

Comment: I think is because you not initialize it. Try `weightLimit = ""`

Comment: when I tried printing just the line, it output all the the tuples.

Comment: I just tried doing weightLimit = "" and it still printed out 575 four times

Comment: Can I see you code? How you asign weightLimit and when you print? If you print in while is normal you have weightLimit four times

Comment: oh snap that was it! I moved it after '}' before fileReader.close(); and that solved it! thanks so much friend!

Comment: so i've been trying to get to the next step of the algorithm which is the actual greedy part but all of my values from the map are inaccessible outside the while loop. is there a way I can make them available in the rest of the program?

Comment: yes you need to change your Map inside your `main method` to the `main class` (`readstringastext`) and Map need to be static exemple : `public class readstringastext {
        public static Map<String,String> map = new HashMap<String, String>(); 
        public static void main(String[] args) { ...`

Comment: so when I try to call either values[0] or values[1] it still gives me an error saying i need to create a local variable, class, parameter or constant. should I be declaring these as variables up top? I think i should be declaring weightLimit up top since I need it elsewhere but I'm not sure about the values

Comment: if you need `weightLimit` in other class you need to do the same thing that Map before.

Comment: And if you want access `values[0]` and `values[1]` outside of the if you need to deplace it too.

Comment: Can you edit your code to show that. I tried in my file but can't seem to get it to work. I edited the code in my question.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you want to pass in the weight/value pair into a map data structure, I modified your code a little below to enable this:

```
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

    try {
        File file = new File("test.txt");
        FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(file);
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(fileReader);
        StringBuffer stringBuffer = new StringBuffer();
        String line;
        String weightLimit = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get("test.txt")).get(0);
        int count = 0;
        while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
            if (count != 0) { // ignore the first line
                String[] splitValue = line.split(" ");
                map.put(splitValue[0], splitValue[1]);
            }     
            count++;
        }
        fileReader.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
//        for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : map.entrySet()) {
//            System.out.println(entry.getKey());
//            System.out.println(entry.getValue());
//        }
   }
```